# How to call javascript from applet without use showDocument?

Tags: javascript, firefox, applet

I'm using

```
getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("javascript:" + command));
```

to call javascript from applet.

But sometimes in firefox this doen't work, I don't know why.

So, now I'm trying to use JSObject, using this:

```
    JSObject jsObject = new JSObject();
    jsObject.eval(command);
```

But I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "thread applet-com.foo.bar.TestApplet-6"
java.lang.InstantiationError: netscape.javascript.JSObject
```

Why I'm getting this error?

There is another way to do java applet to javascript communication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using

```
JSObject jsObject = JSObject.getWindow(this);
jsObject.eval(....);
```

And it works now.